# Functional scoring does not work with node js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am facing a problem with Functional_scoring in elasticsearch.When i am trying to run the functional scoring query from the nodejs.It always gives me error

```
Trace: [illegal_argument_exception] request [/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [query]
    at Logger.trace (/Users/rajeshjain/projects/search/logger.js:39:42)
    at elasticClient.instance.search.then.catch.e (/Users/rajeshjain/projects/search/search/disc_cube_topic.js:117:28)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

The functional_scope query which i am trying to run is

```
{
    "from": "0",
    "size": "20",
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Devel",
                    "analyzer": "standard",
                    "fields": [
                        "topic_name",
                        "cube_name"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "Math.log1p(10*doc['num_cube_members'].value + 5*doc['message_count'].value + doc['num_topic_members'].value)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the node js code which trying to run it is

```
elasticClient.instance.search(query).then(eres => {
            // 3. reformat elasticsearch response and send to client.
            let response = {
                total: eres.hits.total,
                extracted: eres.hits.hits.length,
                results: []
            };
            elasticHitResult4DiscoverableTopicCubes(eres.hits.hits).then(results => {
                response.results = results;
                res.status(200).send(response);
            });
        })
```

It seems to give me error related with the query which is being used with the functional_query...whereas when i run the same queru on kibana..it gives me appropriate results.

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out this issue myself.The difference is..search api from the nodejs expect body as a part of the request..I have added body tag when compare it with the original problematic json.

```
{
"from": "0",
"size": "20",
"body": {
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Devel",
                    "analyzer": "standard",
                    "fields": [
                        "topic_name",
                        "cube_name"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "Math.log1p(10*doc['num_cube_members'].value + 5*doc['message_count'].value + doc['num_topic_members'].value)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: While answering your own question is great, you *should* make it a good answer and explain what the change is and any other relevant details. As it is, it is hard to see quickly what it different.